# How to fix bootstrap column height issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have one dropdown inside bootstrap grid, If I click the dropdown the height of the row also increase, Here not increasing.

How do I do it?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"> 
            <select name="cars" id="cars">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
     border: 1px solid;
     height:auto;
 }

.col-md-4 .col-sm-8 .col-sm-4{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: block;
}
```

**Current outcome:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

[image]

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-grid-system-z8bqwk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I don't think you can do that using the native select element, the best way about it is to just create your custom dropdown component.
I can provide an example if you're open to that solution

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can style the native dropdown list so it's options take space on the page, so I provided an alternative with your desired outcome using a custom dropdown.

**Check this:**

```js
// Get all elements needed
const dropdownBtn = document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn');
const dropdownList = document.querySelector('.dropdown-list');

// Event listener to toggle the dropdown list visibility
dropdownBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dropdownList.classList.toggle('show');
});

// Event listener for option selection
dropdownList.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    const selectedOption = event.target.textContent;
    // Display the selected option in the button
    
    // dropdown Value
    const selectedOptionValue = event.target.getAttribute('value');
    
    dropdownBtn.textContent = selectedOption;
    // Hide the dropdown list after selection
    dropdownList.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
     border: 1px solid;
     height:auto;
 }

.col-md-4 .col-sm-8 .col-sm-4{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: block;
}


/* Basic styling for the dropdown container */
.custom-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Styling for the dropdown button */
.dropdown-btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Styling for the dropdown list */
.dropdown-list {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Styling for the dropdown list items */
.dropdown-list li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Show the dropdown list on hover/focus */
.custom-dropdown:hover .dropdown-list,
.custom-dropdown:focus-within .dropdown-list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="custom-dropdown" name="cars" id="cars">
          <button class="dropdown-btn">Select Option</button>
          <ul class="dropdown-list">
            <li value="volvo">Volvo</li>
            <li value="saab">Saab</li>
            <li value="opel">Opel</li>
            <li value="audi">Audi</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

You can access the dropdown value in the variable `selectedOptionValue`.

Comment: Your concept not working

Comment: It would help if you elaborate further how it isn't achieving the desired outcome :-)